# Is it supported to put animation class on ng-view and on element inside the view in Angular 1.2-rc2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

Everything is in the title!

I'm using Angular 1.2-rc2 and I can't put an animation class on an ng-view AND and on element inside the view.

- If I put animation class on ng-view, animation works on ng-view but not on element inside the view.
- If I remove animation class on ng-view, animation works on all elements with animation class.

Is it supported ? If not, do you know if I can make a workaround with a directive ?

Comment: Can you create a plunker with some example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug of 1.2.0-rc2 release. Without changing any line of code, the issue has been resolved in 1.2.0-rc3.

Answer (score 0):

You should use existing classes defined by AngularJS (ng-enter, ng-leave, ng-enter-active, ng-leave-active, etc.).

To put animation on nested elements, you should use CSS selectors. Here is [a working example](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive%3angView) that demonstrates how to use animation on a ngView.